# Remove all characters not like desired value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL server 2012, and I have an issue with certain values. I want to extract a specific set of values from a string (which is in the entire column) and want to just retrieve the specific value.

The value is: `SS44\\230433\586` and in other value it's `230084android`, and the third `orderno  239578`

The common denominator is that all numbers start with 23, and are 6 characters long. All other values have to be removed from the string. I tried `rtrim` and a `ltrim` but that didn't give me the desired output.

I'm not sure as to how to do this without regex.

Comment: Consider doing string processing in your application code rather than database code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find the start of the number and [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the next 6 digits:

```
declare @Value varchar(50) = 'SS44\\230433\586'
select substring(@Value, patindex('%23%', @Value), 6)
```

If you want to be a bit more careful with the searching, you can use `PATINDEX` and check next 4 symbols - are they digits:

```
patindex('%23[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @Value)
```

Eventually, you can store the result returned and check is there a match:

```
declare @Value varchar(50) = 'SS44\\230433\586'
declare @StartIndex int
set @StartIndex = patindex('%23[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @Value)
select IIF(@StartIndex > 0, substring(@Value, @StartIndex, 6), null)
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed! Thanks!